# ¿Cómo actualizar las cantidades de un carrito de compras hecho en PHP, sesiones y Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, sesiones

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.
Estoy armando, a modo de aprendizaje y para poder aplicarlo en un futuro, un carrito de compras. Funciona todo bien por ahora. Pero tengo una duda con la actualización de las cantidades.

El código que sirve para crear las variables iniciales, al momento de cargar los productos al carrito es este, el mismo funciona perfecto.

Primero se envían, vía post, las variables (solamente pongo el campo de cantidad para ahorrar código):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="idCatalogo" id="id" value="<?php echo $idCatalogo;?>">
    <input type="number" name="Cantidad" id="Cantidad" min="1" max="100" value="<?php echo 1;?>">
    <button name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit">Agregar al Carrito</button>
</form>
```

Estos valores pasan al script para que se agreguen dentro de la sesión:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnAccion'])){
    switch($_POST['btnAccion']){
        case 'Agregar':
            if(is_numeric($_POST['idCatalogo'])){
                $idCatalogo=$_POST['idCatalogo'];
            } else { }  
            if(is_numeric($_POST['Cantidad'])){
                $Cantidad=$_POST['Cantidad'];
            } else { }          
            if(!isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                $producto=array(
                    'idCatalogo'=>$idCatalogo,
                    'Cantidad'=>$Cantidad
                    );
                    $_SESSION['carrito'][0]=$producto;
                    $mensaje="Agregado";            
            } else {
                $idProductos=array_column($_SESSION['carrito'],'idCatalogo');
                if(in_array($idCatalogo,$idProductos)){
                    $mensaje="Duplicado";
                } else {
                $NumeroProductos=count($_SESSION['carrito']);
                $producto=array(
                    'idCatalogo'=>$idCatalogo,
                    'Cantidad'=>$Cantidad
                    );
                    $_SESSION['carrito'][$NumeroProductos]=$producto;
                    $mensaje="Agregado";
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Hasta acá todo perfecto.
Como verán, se controla que el producto no se haya cargado previamente.
Se usa "Case" para el botón, por ende hay uno que sirve para agregar y otro que sirve para eliminar el producto en caso de que el usuario se arrepienta. Y tengo los mensajes, básicos de "agregado", "duplicado" y "eliminado" (este último no lo agregué).

Mi pregunta es:
**¿Cómo hago para crear una instrucción que me permita "Editar" el valor de "Cantidad"?**
Entiendo que debo crear otro "Case" con un "form" y un botón editar junto con un campo "number" igual al que ya uso, pero no logro completar el script que me permita hacer esa edición.

Gracias, y espero haber sido claro en la consulta.

Comment: Si el producto ya se encuentra en el carrito, en vez de mostrar el mensaje "Duplicado", podrías incrementar la cantidad; esta es la funcionalidad esperada en el listado de productos, sin embargo, tal vez convenga poder modificar la cantidad de cada producto cuando se está viendo el carrito, pero necesitas mostrar esa parte del código para poder tratar de ayudar.

Comment: @Triby, gracias por la respuesta.
En realidad, eso de Duplicado se da porque originalmente está hecho pensando en que el producto se pueda agregar una sola vez, o sea, sólo una unidad. Pero, lógicamente, luego me di cuenta de que no me servía sólo una unidad de cada producto.

Comment: ...Entonces, lo que quiero saber es cómo hacer una instrucción que me permita editar la Cantidad. El campo, y el form lo puedo hacer, pero no logro llegar al código que me permita editar esa variable $Cantidad...